# use battery to generate weak electric field?

Tags: batteries, resistors, electric-field

i am a biology student interested in how marine animals react to weak electric fields.  My professor and I want to do a trial experiment and were hoping to rig something up ourselves for cheap.  Is there a simple way to generate a very weak electric field in sea water (on the order of microvolts)?  I thought of using a battery with two leads placed about 1 cm apart to generate an electric field that is essentially localized to the ends of the lead.  A 1.5 volt battery is way too strong though.  Would it work to add resistors?  How best to calculate the amount of resistance needed - or is this just ridiculous to even consider?  Is there an off-the-shelf solution? Or do I need to tell my professor this is impossible without specially engineered equipment?

Comment: You're going to want to know the conductivity of your water, I think. Note that microvolts is not a unit of electric field; electric field strength is measured in volts per meter.

Comment: And by the second part of that comment I mean: please clarify your requirements. I suspect this will not be that difficult a thing to do, it's just not clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: It is not tremendously difficult to generate small voltages, even at substantial currents.  You should talk to your professor to better define what you want to test and bring the information back here to get better advice.  Describe the range of signals you'd like to test, the ideal test space (do you *want* your electrodes 1cm apart or would it be better to have a large chamber and electrodes 1m apart?  Is this a device to roam the sea floor with, or do you intend to use caged fish?

Comment: My first thought is put a resistor in series in the circuit, to make a voltage divider using the resistor and the seawater. The resistance you need in the resistor would be related to the seawater's resistance, so you'd have to measure that.

Comment: There is a difference between an electric field and a current. Using electrodes will generate an electric field AND a current that will corrode the electrodes and introduce electrolysis products into the water. Capacitively coupled conductors will not produce either a current or electrolysis.

Comment: @EdgarBrown The *corrosion* depends on the materials used for electrolyte & electrodes. [Graphite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite#Electrodes) is pretty inert for your typical electrolytes, meaning that it does not corrode as much, compared to other materials.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I used “corrosion” as a layman shorthand for the more appropriate terms reduction/oxidation (redox) reactions. Even though carbon itself is relatively inert, at a high enough voltage (as little as 1V) all conductive materials (including salt water) will undergo redox reactions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with creating a known stable electric field in sea water to see its influence on marine animals.

1) When a current passes through sea water it changes the chemistry. I would wager that sea animals also respond to the gradients of chemicals that would be released by the action of the current just a strongly as to the electric field. It's a major part of the experiment design to separate the two effects.

2) The voltage measured between electrodes and the sea water depends on the electrode material (think battery), and the recent history of the current that's flowed in or out of the water in the vicinity of the electrode (in batteries, this is called polarisation). As the current flows, and as time passes, the polarisation potential changes. This means that what you measure on the electrodes could be a volt or so different from the potential in the free body of sea water. Trying to establish what the electrical field in the water is, to \$\mu V\$, using measurements at electrodes that could be a varying volt or so wrong, is clearly doomed.

It's going to very easy to poke a couple of wires from a battery into a test cell and see animals react. It's going to be very hard to do it in a way that's *reproducable*, especially by others.

I think your best bet, even for a 'quick look see', will be to use a 4 terminal setup (look up Kelvin connection).

Use a porous pot, or similar semi-permeable membrane, submerged in a larger vessel. Your animals and sense electrodes go in the pot. Your drive electrodes are outside the pot. This will isolate chemical changes at the current carrying electrodes entering the experimental area.

Sense the field within the pot with an identical pair of non-reactive electrodes connected to a meter. Platinum electrodes would be good and reproducable, though stainless steel, nickel or carbon might do for an initial test.

Drive the field with a pair of electrodes outside the pot. Similar considerations for electrode materials, though they don't need to be identical. Initially, an adjustable lab power supply will be all you need, keep adjusting it by hand to keep your sensed field constant. Later, you can add a feedback amplifier to drive the electrodes to keep your sensed field constant. The amplifier is the easy bit, come back here once you have the rest of the setup going, and we can help you with that.

Comment: As the question talks about “electric field” a purely capacitive setup should also work.

Comment: This is really helpful.  We will try this pot-in-a-pot approach.  To clarify what we want to do, we have a 30 gal aquarium into which we'll introduce starfish and other invertebrate animals.  We want to see if the animals will be attracted to or avoid or ignore a localized electric field.  Clearly we need not to electrocute the animals and we want our electric field to be small and relatively reproducible.  Thanks!